# How to read and load file in bigquery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

how Read csv file and load it into bigquery via dataflow - Instead of templates, use python coding for this in GCP cloud console
and same how  Do the above similar thing using terraform instead of cloud console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you want to use dataflow?

Comment: If you don’t have many transformations to apply, no need to use Dataflow. You can directly load csv file on Bigquery, via console, bq command or Terraform resource.

Comment: Hi I want to  load the data to bigquery  through python  using dataflow  
What is the process for it?With my  CSV datas, i have to write a "parser", some kind of code that extract every field from each record of my  file.
How i approach for code and it complete process